# Cisco ASA 5506-X: clients periodically lose Internet access

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Clients periodically lose Internet access, but I can connect to Cisco ASA and manage it. If i am ping sites, it works:

```
Minsk# ping yandex.ru
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 77.88.55.60, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 20/24/30 ms
```

The problem is only observed for users. Solved by the command: clear xlate.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is typical of a full translation table:

For each connection that is made through the device, there's a record in a table. This table has of course a limited size and once it is full, new connections cannot be made.

The `clear xlate` command empty the table and thus allow new connections (but of course reset all existing connections).

You have to investigate why there's so many connections at the same time. To do so, you can use the `show xlate detail` and `show conn details` commands.

As explained in comment by @Jesse P. one option to workaround the issue is to lower the xlate timeout, but you still should investigate what consumes the connections.

Also another possible explanation (thanks @Ricky Beam) is that you hit the limit of licensed users.

Comment: You should make sure your xlate timeout interval is not something crazy high.  The default value is usually fine but it can be adjusted to meet your needs.

Comment: Or you're hitting the licensed number of users.

Comment: @JesseP. 3 hours by default.

Comment: @Ruslan Right, but if there are enough connections to exhaust the limit before some start timing out, that needs to be lowered.  Some compliance policies want it lowered to 30 minutes, which may fit this case well, too.